# Check if Offline with GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using [Offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/) integrated with GWT to check if app is offline (i.e. server is down).

The library works fine and the problem I have now is how to test it in Dev Mode, if I manually shut down the jetty server, the app also goes down. Unlike with when deployed with Tomcat or JBoss. Is there a way to test this in Dev Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a custom js library why not just add a client heartbeat checker? Then the RPC call from the service will return an [InvocationException](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/InvocationException.html) that you can check for by creating a custom AsyncCallback abstract class. Like so:

```
public abstract class ResponsiveAsyncCallback<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        if(caught instanceof InvocationException) {
            // Failed to connect to the server
            // Do what you like here, maybe create an event
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just need to make sure you call super.onFailure() if you are extending its functionality in the future. Something like this would work a lot better I think.

Answer (score 0):

Compile the app and remove gwt.server query parameter from the URL. A compiled GWT app continues to execute in the browser and you can shut the Dev Mode server and start it up again to see the effect on your app.